# Using ibeacon technology with delphi firemonkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, ibeacon

We are trying to use a ibeacon technology with delphi xe5.

We have tested with xcode and ... seems work fine.

Someone has tried with Delphi ?

thanks
AC

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried with Delphi, but you will need a wrapper around the native iOS Objective C `CoreLocation` APIs, and I do not believe one yet exists yet.  Ideally such a wrapper would also support the [Android iBeacon library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/). I am not a Delphi programmer, but would be interested in assisting any such effort.

A nearer-term iOS-only alternative is to import the Objective C headers to Delphi and access them directly.  [This article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41715) describes how to do that to access the GPS APIs in `CoreLocation`.  The article is from before iBeacons were added to `CoreLocation`, but the same principles should apply.

Comment: I had found the article about "wrapper sdk" ... the work is very hard and I am looking for if someone had started the code ...

it's very strange that nobody interesting this technology

thanks for your answer